# Get Relative Path from Route Name

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, url-routing

When a path is named...

```
[Route("api/[controller]/{id}/Existing", Name = "ExistingOrdersLink")]
public class OrdersController : Controller {...}
```

...it is easy to create an **absolute** path using its name:

```
var address = Url.Link("ExistingOrdersLink", new { id = 22 });
```

However, I need the ability to generate a **relative** path from a Route name.  So I write code like this:

```
//Is there a built-in mechanism for this?
string partial = new Uri(Url.Link("ExistingOrdersLink", new { id = id })).PathAndQuery;
```

The above works but, in ASP.NET Core, is there a more direct way to get the same result?

### Context

Why do I need this?  Some of the controllers I make are actually generic:

```
[Route("api/Subscribers/{id}/[controller]", "SubscriberLink")]
[Route("api/Organization/{id}/[controller]", "OrganizationLink")]
public class OrdersController<T> : Controller where T : IOrder
{
    private ICommand<Order<T>> createOrder;

    protected OrdersController(ICommand<Order<T>> createOrder)
    {
        this.createOrder = createOrder;
    }

    [HttpPost("{otype}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(
        Guid id,
        [FromBody] Order<T> order)
    {
        order.CustomerOrderId = Guid.NewGuid();
        createOrder.Handle(order);

        string[] segs = Request.Path.Value.Split(new char[] { '/' },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        //This will become either "SubscriberLink" or "OrganizationLink"
        string route = $"{segs[1]}Link";

        //Is there a built-in mechanism for this?
        string partial = new Uri(Url.Link(route, new { id = id })).PathAndQuery;

        partial = $"{partial}/{order.CustomerOrderId}";
        CreatedResult reply = Created(partial, null);

        return reply;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for  `Url.RouteUrl`
Example:

```
Url.RouteUrl("ExistingOrdersLink", new { id = 22});
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, although the XML documentation for that function is incorrect.  It states "Generates a fully qualified or absolute URL...".  I would not have asked this question if the documentation had been correct.